# Wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) error in M.Hartl's Rails Tutorial 7.4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I've been following the latest version of M.Hartl's Rails tutorial and I've encountered a problem at Chapter 7.4.1. I've created a signup form which is associated with the new action of the users controller. When the form is submitted with valid information the controller should redirect to the new users profile, however I incur the error below...

I've included the routes.rb code as well as the Users controller code. Could anyone help me?

When I access the url ..**/users/1** the page actually renders my user, so I know the user has been created and saved to the database. I don't know if maybe it is an error in the implementation of the **redirect_to** method?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

---

**ArgumentError in UsersController#create
wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)**

Extracted source (around line #19):

```
private
  def _compute_redirect_to_location_with_xhr_referer(options)
    store_for_turbolinks begin
      if options == :back && request.headers["X-XHR-Referer"]
        _compute_redirect_to_location_without_xhr_referer(request.headers["X-XHR-Referer"])
```

---

Users Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)  
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private 

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

Routes.rb :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root             'static_pages#home'
  get 'help'    => 'static_pages#help'
  get 'about'   => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get 'signup'  => 'users#new'
  resources :users
end
```

Comment: looks similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21221888/ror-argumenterror-in-sessionscontrollercreate-wrong-number-of-arguments-1-fo)

Comment: Could you post the contents of params from the error page?

Comment: Post the full error with stack trace

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like your version of turbolinks is old. Try updating to the latest:

`gem 'turbolinks', '~> 2.3.0'`

Comment: @StevanPopovic , you should click the link to "accept" this answer.

Comment: @lugolabs Can you explain why the turbolinks version fixes this problem?

Comment: This happens when you have a certain version of **turbolinks** on your Gemfile, but the Rails version installed expects another version. E.g. when you upgrade Rails versions manually.